How to implement a DuckDB query timeout
I am trying to execute queries on a large duckdb connection that takes user inputs, some inputs may end up taking too long and I am having trouble figuring out how to time out the queries in the event they take >2 min to conserve resources
Signal is not an option for me since I am not using the main thread
I can not utilize a lot of common libraries that use pickle since duckdb connections are not pickleable
Using concurrent futures has odd behavior for me where the timeout will occur, but then my grpc server response will not continue
def query_timeout(self, request, dev_oid):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(query_duckdb, request, self.duckdb_client)
        try:
            # Get the result within timeout (10 seconds)
            result = future.result(timeout=10)
            # Return the result
            return result
        except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
            logger.info(f"Query Timeout on request: {request}")
            return "Timed out", None

above is the way I tried to implement that
Any solution is viable etc. using grpc server timeouts, python timeouts, or duckdb settings
